# Remote server (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to connect to an http web page , but everytime it enters in catch and returns error **Remote server (407) Proxy Authentication Required.** why? I used the same code in another website project and it worked.

```
WebProxy wp = new WebProxy("**");
        wp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("**", "**");
        StringBuilder sbXmlText = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
            MyWebClient.Proxy = wp;
            Stream TheStream = MyWebClient.OpenRead("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates10days.xml");
            StreamReader TheStreamReader = new StreamReader(TheStream);
            while (!TheStreamReader.EndOfStream)
                sbXmlText.Append((char)TheStreamReader.Read());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mail_send_bnr(ex.ToString(), "Error on connecting to bnr", "test");
        }
```

Comment: Have you checked if YOU have a proxy half-configured in YOUR browser?

Comment: I use the same proxy in another code the same project and it works

Comment: I just went to your URL and I was able to access the page without any proxy or credentials. There are different excahnge rates from the bank of Romania. Are you sure you need to go through a proxy?

Comment: Yes , because otherwise it appears error Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: So you need proxy because you cannot access  http://www.bnr.ro/ in your app/server, case I don't follow you?